# R code Error: unexpected input in "group = as.factor(rep(c(“"

Tags: r

I found these lines of R code in my lecture notes (they are supposed to be correct):

```
word = c(700, 850, 820, 640, 920, 480, 460, 500, 570, 580, 500, 550, 480, 600, 610)
group = as.factor(rep(c(“X”, “Y”, “Z”), each = 5))
```

I copied and pasted each line into R, but I received an error message:

```
> word = c(700, 850, 820, 640, 920, 480, 460, 500, 570, 580, 500, 550, 480, 600, 610)
> group = as.factor(rep(c(“X”, “Y”, “Z”), each = 5))
Error: unexpected input in "group = as.factor(rep(c(“"
```

How do I solve this problem? Thanks.

I intend to use the result of these lines of code to further do the following :

> summary(aov(word~group))

(This is for a homework which is near due. I appreciate very much your replies.)

Comment: The quotes in your vector are "fancy quotes", where the left and right quote marks look different. This is often auto-corrected if the code is copy/pasted into Microsoft Word, a Google Doc, or similar. You need plain quotes for code.

Comment: What GregorThomas means is for you to change `“` and `”` into `"`

Comment: Thanks GregorThomas and Onyambu! Turns out that was indeed the problem.